# backfill values for only selected members of group - pandas

Tags: pandas

This should be simple, but took me too many rows to complete:

I have a pandas data frame indexed by **id** and **year**.

For the groups A and B, I want to backfill only the values of 2022 to 2021 (2019 values should be left untouched). See table below.

This worked in the end, but cumbersome:

```
df = df.swaplevel()
# create a frame with backfilled values
dfbf = df.loc[[2021,2022]].groupby('id')['value'].bfill(limit=1).to_frame()
df = df.join(dfbf, rsuffix = '_fill')
df = df.reset_index(level = "id")
df['value'].loc[2021] = df.loc[2021][['value', 'value_fill']].sum(axis = 1)
df = df.set_index(['id'], append=True).swaplevel()
```

Example:

|  |  | value |  |  |  | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **id** | **year** |  |  | **id** | **year** |  |
| A | 2019 |  |  | A | 2019 |  |
| A | 2020 | 1 |  | A | 2020 | 1 |
| A | 2021 |  |  | A | 2021 | 3 |
| A | 2022 | 3 |  | A | 2022 | 3 |
| B | 2019 |  |  | B | 2019 |  |
| B | 2020 | 12 |  | B | 2020 | 12 |
| B | 2021 |  |  | B | 2021 | 11 |
| B | 2022 | 11 |  | B | 2022 | 11 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select rows by first by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html) with [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.loc[:, [2021,2022], :].groupby('id')['value'].bfill(limit=1))
print (df)
         value
id year       
A  2019    NaN
   2020    1.0
   2021    3.0
   2022    3.0
B  2019    NaN
   2020   12.0
   2021   11.0
   2022   11.0
```

Or use mask for expected rows (filtered in both sides for improve performance - processing only selected rows, not all rows):

```
#include
m = df.index.get_level_values('year').isin([2021,2022])
#exclude
#m = df.index.get_level_values('year') != 2019
df.loc[m, 'value'] = df[m].groupby('id')['value'].bfill(limit=1)
print (df)
         value
id year       
A  2019    NaN
   2020    1.0
   2021    3.0
   2022    3.0
B  2019    NaN
   2020   12.0
   2021   11.0
   2022   11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subset the values to replace using `loc` and a condition on the 'year' level to avoid 2019:

```
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('year')!=2019] = df.groupby(level=0).bfill()
```

output:

```
         value
id year       
A  2019    NaN
   2020    1.0
   2021    3.0
   2022    3.0
B  2019    NaN
   2020   12.0
   2021   11.0
   2022   11.0
```

Comment: ya, in term of performance is necessary filter in both sides like in my answer.

Comment: @jezrael You mean to avoid computing the fill unnecessary for 2019?

Comment: I think generally.

Comment: Unless really needed, I usually prefer readability for a first shot. But I always appreciate your insightful answers and comments, you seem to have mastered the performance aspects of pandas :)

Comment: hmmm, readability for add `df[m]` vs `df` is less readable? I think not. Only if pass 2 masks for 2 sides, then agree, it is worse readable.

Comment: Well, it's subjective, I meant as a whole (extra line, extra variable, etc.). But again, my comment was meant as compliment to you, just pointing I like that you try to optimize everything from the beginning ;)

Comment: Ya, thinking about it ;) Happy coding!